# getting the first value of a null initialized array of strings

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to get the first value of a null initialed array of string.I have tried every method I can think of with no luck. I either get warning, errors, or a segmentation fault. Whats the correct way to print the null value and use it in the if statement? Once I get this figured out I would like to get that for loop at the end printing the strings not equal to null.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char *strings_line_tokens[503] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    strings_line_tokens[0] = malloc(strlen("cookies")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[0], "cookies");

    strings_line_tokens[2] = malloc(strlen("FOOBAR")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[2], "FOOBAR");

    printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %s\n",strings_line_tokens[0]);
    printf("-------------------\n");

    printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",(char)strings_line_tokens[1], (int)strings_line_tokens[1]);
    printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");

    printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",strings_line_tokens[1], strings_line_tokens[1]);
    printf("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n");

    printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",(char)strings_line_tokens[1][0], (int)strings_line_tokens[1][0]);
    printf("ccccccccccccccccccc\n");

    printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",strings_line_tokens[1][0], strings_line_tokens[1][0]);
    printf("-------------------\n");

    if(strings_line_tokens[1] == 0)
        printf("You have a NULL \n");

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if(strings_line_tokens[i] != 0)
            printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %s\n",strings_line_tokens[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the current warnings that I'm getting.

```
main.c:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
main.c:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
main.c:15: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’
main.c:15: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’
```

Here is the update M.M asked for. Klas Lindbäck showed how to get my ultimate goal which was the for loop working.

From past experience when using a char array that was initialized to `null` %c would give garbage in printf() and %d would give the ascii value of `null` which is 0 in printf(). So I thought one of these would give garbage and the ascii value 0.

```
printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",(char)strings_line_tokens[1], (int)strings_line_tokens[1]);
printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");

printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",strings_line_tokens[1], strings_line_tokens[1]);
printf("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n");

printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",(char)strings_line_tokens[1][0], (int)strings_line_tokens[1][0]);
printf("ccccccccccccccccccc\n");

printf("strings_line_tokens[]: %c %d \n",strings_line_tokens[1][0], strings_line_tokens[1][0]);
printf("-------------------\n");
```

Output I was hoping for with one of them.

```
garbage 0
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Also, you repeating yourself very often. Consider refactoring into more functions. Why are you printing lines of one character again and again?

Comment: there are 2 errors in your code. `int i = 0`is missing `; ` and you end the block of your loop with `{` instead of `}`

Comment: strings_line_tokens[1] is of type char*, so casting to char or int does not make sense here. The only thing that should work as expected is the last and second to last printf using strings_line_tokens[1][0] which is of type char.

Comment: @AustinWBryan I am trying to get that for loop at the end working. I am trying to show what I have tried. None of those methods are working.

Comment: @Flikk Thank you. They have been fixed.

Comment: @SouravGhosh are you saying this didn't work `char *strings_line_tokens[503] = {0};`? I that initialized `strings_line_tokens[0]` , `strings_line_tokens[1] ` and so on to null.

Comment: @rockstar797 Sorry, I did not notice the format specifiers. Please ignore.

Comment: could you show what output you expected from the first two of the lines containing `%c %d` ? It's hard to tell what you are trying to do (and your compiler agrees)

Comment: @M.M I added an update. Is it possible to get `garbage 0` like I was hoping for? I would still like to know that if possible :). And as I said Klas Lindbäck got my ultimate for of the for loop working.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop is already working.

I removed the trial-and-error code and kept just the `for` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char *strings_line_tokens[503] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    strings_line_tokens[0] = malloc(strlen("cookies")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[0], "cookies");

    strings_line_tokens[2] = malloc(strlen("FOOBAR")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[2], "FOOBAR");

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if(strings_line_tokens[i] != 0)
            printf("strings_line_tokens[%d]: %s\n", i,strings_line_tokens[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
strings_line_tokens[0]: cookies
strings_line_tokens[2]: FOOBAR
```

There is no right way to print a null value. I would just add an else clause that printed what I wanted, for example the string `null`:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("strings_line_tokens[%d]: %s\n", i, strings_line_tokens[i] == 0 ? "null": strings_line_tokens[i]);
```

or (if you prefer regular `if` over the ternary if):

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    if (strings_line_tokens[i] == 0) {
        printf("strings_line_tokens[%d]: %s\n", i, "null");
    } else {
        printf("strings_line_tokens[%d]: %s\n", i, strings_line_tokens[i]);
    }
```

New output:

```
strings_line_tokens[0]: cookies
strings_line_tokens[1]: null
strings_line_tokens[2]: FOOBAR
```

Comment: Can you please remind me what the shorthand if else notation means? I have not seen that in awhile.

Comment: @rockstar797 Added the regular `if` equivalent.